# How to store api url in zf2 local.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to store an API url in my local.php file. Can anyone tell me how to inject the stored value from local.php to Factory / Controller?. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your configuration - `local.php`

```
return [
    'api' => 'http://api.test.com',
];
```

The factory of your controller inserting the ApiUrl

```
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $apiUrl = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['api'];

        return new IndexController($apiUrl);
    }
}
```

The Controller receiving the ApiUrl from the factory and local.php:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $apiUrl;

    public function __construct($apiUrl)
    {
        $this->apiUrl = $apiUrl;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $apiUrl = $this->apiUrl;

        // do stuff

        // return data
    }
}
```

Comment: one small additional question: how can I inject this url in a Service? So in your example, in the IndexControllerFactory I instantiate an api service and I need to pass it this link.

Comment: In your ServiceFactory, don't get the parent ServiceLocator as the ServiceLocator is the ServiceManager in there. So instead of `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')` you should just simply get it by `$serviceLocator->get('Config')`

Comment: ok I got that part, but in my case I have something like `$apiService = $realServiceLocator->get('Application\Services\ApiServiceInterface');`
and I want to inject the api link into the interface with `$serviceLocator->get('Config')['api'];`. Any solutions for this?

Comment: I got a workaround .. :)
in my Factory, after I initialize the $apiService I am doing something like:
`$apiService->setUrl($serviceLocator->get('Config')['api'])' and I just add a setter in my ApiService class and I have it directly. do you think this is a good approach? thank you

Comment: It depends if you want to change the URL if you've got the service. Now you can overwrite the ApiUrl with the setter. When passing it by the `__constructor()`  and have no setter available, you can't overwrite it. So it is up to you if you want to change it later on or it is pretty much static. But you don't need to change it, so up to you to decide if you allow the programmers to change it or not.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this module: https://github.com/Eye4web/zf2-site-config
It has convenience methods for controllers and views, and a service you can DI.
Furthermore it can read from a lot of different file types.